# Prepend/append to cucumber scenario name/feature name or tags at runtime

Tags: ruby, cucumber

When running cucumber suite for different viewports desktop/mobile, I'd like to prepend ENV['VIEWPORT'] value to either Feature name or Scenario name at runtime so I can see in the HTML report the viewport for which the scenario failed. I am generating a unified HTML report my merging all viewport reports. Each scenario can run on any platform based on the ENV flag above so tagging scenarios by viewport is not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement some custom formatters for your custom formats.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Custom-Formatters

Then, similar to https://github.com/moredip/timestamped-scenarios, assuming the **cucumber** `2.4.0` version and **bundler** are used:

## Formatter

```
# features/support/viewport_aware/adds_viewport.rb
require 'rubygems'

module ViewportAware
  module AddsViewport
    def self.formatter_with_viewport(formatter_class)
      Class.new( formatter_class ){ include AddsViewport }
    end

    def scenario_name(keyword, name, file_colon_line, source_indent)
      super(keyword, with_viewport(name), file_colon_line, source_indent)
    end

    def feature_name(keyword, name)
      super(with_viewport(keyword), name)
    end

    # for json formatter
    def on_finished_testing(event)
      @feature_hashes.each do |it|
        it[:name] = with_viewport(it[:name])
        (it[:elements] || []).each do |el|
          el[:name] = with_viewport(el[:name])
        end
      end
      super
    end

    private

    def with_viewport(str)
      "#{str} <<#{ENV['VIEWPORT']}>>"
    end
  end
end
```

## Pretty Formatter

```
# features/support/viewport_aware/pretty_formatter.rb

require 'cucumber/formatter/pretty'
module ViewportAware
  PrettyFormatter = AddsViewport.formatter_with_viewport(Cucumber::Formatter::Pretty)
end
```

## HTML Formatter

```
# features/support/viewport_aware/html_formatter.rb

require 'cucumber/formatter/html'
module ViewportAware
  HtmlFormatter = AddsViewport.formatter_with_viewport(Cucumber::Formatter::Html)
end
```

## JSON Formatter

```
# features/support/viewport_aware/json_formatter.rb

require 'cucumber/formatter/json'
module ViewportAware
  JsonFormatter = AddsViewport.formatter_with_viewport(Cucumber::Formatter::Json)
end
```

Then run:

```
VIEWPORT=mobile bundle exec cucumber -f ViewportAware::PrettyFormatter
```

or

```
VIEWPORT=mobile bundle exec cucumber -f ViewportAware::HtmlFormatter
```

or

```
VIEWPORT=mobile bundle exec cucumber -f ViewportAware::JsonFormatter
```

As a result of pretty format:

```
Feature <<mobile>>: Create a boat
  In order to avoid mistakes when finding my boat
  As a sailor of my boat
  I want to be told the details of my boat

  Scenario: Creating a new boat <<mobile>>                              
  <skimmed>
```

or JSON Formatter:

```
[
  {
    "uri": "features/add.feature",
    "id": "create-a-boat",
    "keyword": "Feature",
    "name": "Create a boat <<mobile>>",
    "description": "  In order to avoid mistakes when finding my boat\n  As a sailor of my boat\n  I want to be told the details of my boat",
    "line": 1,
    "elements": [
      {
        "id": "create-a-boat;creating-a-new-boat",
        "keyword": "Scenario",
        "name": "Creating a new boat <<mobile>>",
```

Comment: Thanks @eugene. That's brilliant. I tested this and it worked for HTML and Pretty but not for JSON. Any way I can get this to work with JSON formatter? I tried adding a constant like above but looks like json formatter works a bit differently

Comment: I've extended the answer.
Note the removed 'initialize'.
This patch became messy (and more like a regural monkey-patch) but it is still works.
You may refactor it as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot @eugene. Works as expected.